# Replace Android with real Linux in smartphones?

Tags: linux, smartphone

I always wondered if, android is a linux derived SO, why I can't just compile a Gentoo (for example) with correct arch, and little modifications in boot to fully replace android.

I know that I may miss some functions, but having already kernel sources, and existing AOSP ROMs, and even, with UbuntuOS, I think it should be possible.

The only problem I have is that I don't know anything about the boot process, so even if I could manage to build an image, I wouldn't know how to boot it.

Any hints, information, or advises about this area?

P.S. In this case is a Samsung Galaxy S3 (I-9300), but could be applicable to other brands as well.

Comment: As always, drivers...

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what I want is to manage it to boot. Having driver problems is not the issue.